# How to exclude results with no refferrer in a Kibana (Apache Lucene) query?

Tags: apache, logging, lucene, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to monitor 404 and 503 errors using Kibana on our service. I'm trying to build a query that will be optimal for other users, so they won't see as much noise in results. I realize my query could be pretty bad as I have no experience with Apache Lucene whatsoever, just trying to figure it out.

Currently the query is this:

```
(@fields.method:(GET OR POST OR HEAD) AND 
 @fields.response_code:(404 OR 503)) 
-@fields.agent:(bingbot,msnbot,googlebot,nekstbot,w2gbot,AhrefsBot,ia_archive,facebookexternalhit,AdsBot-Google)
```

I'm having a problem with results that have no refferrer, displaying

```
@fields.referrer "-"
```

but I don't know how to exclude results with no referrer. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a thing about Kibana, but in Lucene `-` has a special meaning. If you want to filter out values having `-`, you need to escape it. So the query would be

```
-@fields.referrer:\-
```

This might or might not work, but you can give it a try. More details on Lucene query syntax are available [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the table panel view there is a clickable 'Add filter to NOT match this value' (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RiFt.jpg), but it doesn't work for me in Kibana 3.1.2 for referrer "-"